# How to change color for creating new contact

Tags: ios, ios10, xcode8, cncontactviewcontroller

Our app has a dark navigation bar background tint color and white tint color.  These are set by UIAppearance API.  When we call this code to add a contact, its using that white color for the back button.  How can we set this color for just this view that the OS handles?  Its using the default tint color but we'd like to override it here as much as we are allowed, since white on white isn't visible.

```
        let ucvc = CNContactViewController(forUnknownContact: contact)
        ucvc.delegate = self
        ucvc.allowsEditing = true
        ucvc.allowsActions = true
        ucvc.alternateName = name()
        ucvc.contactStore = CNContactStore()

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ucvc, animated: true)
```

Comment: I'm trying to reset it using UIAppearance and then changing it back, but that doesn't seem to take.  My timing, if that hack works, must be wrong.

Comment: I tried things like UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [CNContactViewController.self]).tintColor = UIColor.purple . I also tried things like  UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.purple
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.purple
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.purple]  before presenting the CNContactViewController but can't make either of them work.

Comment: It will use my tint color, but once I'm in my feature's view controller, I can't tell if its too late to modify the UIAppearance tint color, or the tint color on any of my views, before I create or present the CNContactViewController